# Iterating over XML data in PHP using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have the following Simple XML Data:

```
  [Listeners] => 37
            [listener] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [IP] => 0.0.0.1
                            [UserAgent] => curl/7.19.7 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
                            [Connected] => 1236
                            [ID] => 120
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [IP] => 0.0.0.2
                            [UserAgent] => curl/7.19.7 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
                            [Connected] => 1235
                            [ID] => 121
                        )
```

I want to show [IP].

So I have this PHP script:

```
<?php

$url = "http://admin:password@media.xseu.net/admin/listclients?mount=/FavoriteFM";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
 $IP = $xml->listener->IP;
 echo $IP[0];

?>
```

But it's not working. How can I display display IP in the proper way?

Comment: You should change your password on that service, it's now public.

Comment: Also if you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works! (There you also see how to edit your question; Welcome on SO)

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line:

(You simply forgot the first level source)

```
$IP = $xml->listener->IP;
```

to this:

```
$IP = $xml->source->listener->IP;
        //^^^^^^^^ See here
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it just shows one IP. How to show ALL ip's?

Comment: @DennisdeWit Simply change: `echo $IP[0];` -> `print_r($IP);` or you can use: `foreach($IP as $v) echo $v . "<br />";`

Comment: Can't we make a loop or so? Because I need them as a variable. I want to use $IP later to look up the country that comes with that IP.

Comment: @DennisdeWit The second example is a loop: `foreach($IP as $v) echo $v . "<br />";` ?! Or what do you mean?

Comment: I still get to see only one IP-address.

My goal is to make a script that can show ALL listeners. I want to put every IP into a variable. So later on, I can use that variable to look up the country where that IP comes from. So I want a geostat.

Like: $IP = 0.0.0.0. --> API --> $location = Romania.

Comment: @DennisdeWit Do: `print_r($IP);` If there is only 1 IP then you only have 1 IP in your xml

Comment: I have multiple IP's in my XML:



<listener>
<IP>0.0.0.0</IP>
<UserAgent>
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
</UserAgent>
<Connected>507</Connected>
<ID>285</ID>
</listener>
<listener>
<IP>0.0.0.1</IP>
<UserAgent>WinampMPEG/5.50</UserAgent>
<Connected>383</Connected>
<ID>321</ID>
</listener>

etc..

Comment: @DennisdeWit Please user the edit button: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28377039/edit to post this

Comment: @DennisdeWit Also what is the output of: `print_r($IP);` ?

Comment: Just one IP address

I am now using this:

<?php

$url = "http://user:password@media.xseu.net/admin/listclients?mount=/FavoriteFM";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "<pre>";
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 1000):
$IP = $xml->source->listener[$i]->IP;
 foreach($IP as $v) echo $v . "<br />";
    $i++;
endwhile;



?>


But it sucks, because it will just loop a 1000 times and it's just a dirty workaround.

Comment: @DennisdeWit Now i got it :D This should work for you: `foreach($xml->source->listener as $ip)
 echo $ip->IP . "<br />";`

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://admin:password@media.xseu.net/admin/listclients?mount=/FavoriteFM";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$IP = $xml->source->listener;
    foreach($IP as $row){
      echo $row->IP;
    }
```

You will get all the IPs of array.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
foreach($xml->source->listener as $ip) 
    echo $ip->IP . "<br />";
```